# Use /etc/init.d/fetchmail with the personnal ~/.fetchmailrc

Tags: cron, init.d, procmail, fetchmail

Now, I have two users in my system using `fetchmail` with a personal `~/.fetchmailrc` and syncing there mails with the command `fetchmail -kv --uidl -m '\''/usr/bin/procmail -d %T'\` (In a cron but this isn’t important).

Then, I would like to use the `/etc/init.d/fetchmail` service but always with the personal `fetchmailrc` of this tow users. I wouldn't like to use the `/etc/fetchmailrc` global conf. Is this possible?

I know the possibility to make a global cron but before I would know if what I said is possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ther eisn't really anything out of the box that I'm aware of with `fetchmail` but you could easily construct something yourself like so.

If you had a `start)` section to your `/etc/init.d/fetchmail` service:

```
start)
        # Start daemons.
        echo -n "Starting fetchmail: "
        update_boot_stage 'Starting email fetching service'
    conffile=/etc/fetchmail.conf
    [ -f "$conffile" ]  &&  FETCHMAILHOME=$fetchmailddirs daemon --user=$fetchmailuser /usr/bin/fetchmail --daemon 60 --syslog --fetchmailrc "$conffile"
    if [ ! -d "$fetchmailddir" ];  then
        mkdir "$fetchmailddir"
        chown $fetchmailuser:$fetchmailgroup "$fetchmailddir"
        chmod 700 "$fetchmailddir"
    fi
        for conffile in /etc/fetchmail.conf.d/*.conf;  do
        bname=$(basename "$conffile")
        fetchmailddirsub=$fetchmailddir/$bname
        if [ ! -d "$fetchmailddirsub" ];  then
            mkdir "$fetchmailddirsub"
            chown $fetchmailuser:$fetchmailgroup "$fetchmailddirsub"
            chmod 700 "$fetchmailddirsub"
        fi
        [ -f "$conffile" ]  &&  FETCHMAILHOME=$fetchmailddirsub daemon --user=$fetchmailuser /usr/bin/fetchmail --daemon 60 --syslog --fetchmailrc "$conffile"
        done
        touch /var/lock/subsys/fetchmail
        success "fetchmail started"
        echo
        ;;
```

You could then create links from the directory `/etc/fetchmail.conf.d/` to each user's `.fetchmailrc` file. This would then allow a single fetchmail to include all the user's potentially.

```
 $ ln -s /home/userX/.fetchmailrc /etc/fetchmail.conf.d/userX.conf
```

This is a rough idea that will likely need a bit of tweaking. You'll have to make sure that the `.fetchmailrc` files can be run in this fashion but it should be doable.

A complete example of the stop/start script is available here.

- [Using multiple fetchmail instances for instant gratification](http://fnxweb.com/blog/2012/07/14/using-multiple-fetchmail-instances-for-instant-gratification/)

Comment: Hmm, I don’t have any kind of this code in my `/etc/init.d/fetchmail`. Perhaps because I’m on Gentoo? This is my [`/etc/init.d/fetchmail`](http://codepad.org/i3TUOJTG).

Comment: @fauve - yes this code is a customization to the init.d service file. I've done something similar for a server I maintain, that is not my code, but an example that was similar to my setup.

Comment: I see your code, it testt if `/etc/fetchmail.conf./` contain somting as you say me to create in it a symbolic link to user’s fetchmailrc.
But, there isn’t possible to copy this files in the script? I talk about someting like:

>for user in /home; do
> if [ -f "/home/$user/.fetchmailrc"];  then
>  ln -s /home/$user/.fetchmailrc >/etc/fetchmail.conf.d/$user.conf
> fi
> done

Comment: @fauve - are you asking if you could pull the user's files into your directory instead? Sure you could modify it to do that instead, this was just a rough approach. The key is that `fetchmail` doesn't do anything out of the box and you have to code it yourself. You'll just have to restart the service any time they make a change, if you copy it. I believe this would be fine since even in daemon mode `fetchmail` doesn't monitor the config files for changes, so it requires a restart w/ any mods to those files.